# PProPanel JSX - Basic guide to get started?

Tags: extendscript

I know you can extend Adobe Premiere Pro with [some simple JavaScript](https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/Samples/tree/master/PProPanel). The problem with that link (which I got to through the official Adobe website), is that all of sample code links are outdated (they point to the wrong location of the file, to lines that aren't correct anymore).

The second paragraph instructs you to install a bunch of things, none of which seem like things you "install", and they mention ExtendScript, which I don't understand whether is already installed with my Premiere or not (it's not available on Creative Cloud, and also the links I found on Adobe's website for it are, again, dead). I keep searching online and finding dead links to tutorials that no longer exist. Really, [dead links everywhere](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/2e/0a/7d/2e0a7d3713d4c5ed6acda0b7e28e7e51--link-cosplay-cosplay-costume.jpg).

I'm an experienced developer with good JS background, I just want know what I need, some simple examples of basic usage to get me started and maybe working links to some cheat-sheet I can use when I'm looking for available functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extendscript is the name of the old API for automating Premiere and other Adobe apps. It's built-in and can basically do anything that you can do with the GUI, and it's javascript-based.

There is an IDE for Extendscript, the Extendscript Toolkit (ESTK) which has a debugger and allows you to inspect data etc. It's perplexingly hard to find on the Adobe website; I found it by a duckduckgo search [here](https://www.adobe.com/products/extendscript-toolkit.html), I installed it through the creative cloud desktop manager, though I'm not sure how you do that with the current version.

[image]

As far as documentation goes, you're right, it's dead link city. There is a Javascript Tools Guide included with the Extendscript Toolkit, on windows it's in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe ExtendScript Toolkit CC\SDK\`. That covers creating UI elements, but doesn't explain Premiere's object model. AFAIK there is no official documentation for this, you have to use the ESTK data browser to look for yourself.

The CEP extensions are a new development and allow for easier integration with the host. I think you already have all the documentation there is for it. I'd advise that you pester Adobe to make it easier for developers like yourself to create tools for their users.

Comment: Oh ok, so ESTK is an IDE. I don't see how I can install it through the Creative Cloud, and, as mentioned, the official links I found on Adobe's site are dead. That local documentation doesn't exist since I don't have it installed. And you're also saying there's no official documentation for the object model? This is fucking ridiculous.

Comment: Ok so I found out that in order to install ESTK you need to go into preferences in the Creative Cloud and make sure it also shows "older apps", because of course you do.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. Yeah, I don't understand adobe's attitude to developers either. Adding scripts to their marketplace for AE and Premiere is equally difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Here is for anyone else who gets here from a Google search: You can also go to this link to download the ESTK: https://helpx.adobe.com/download-install/kb/creative-cloud-apps-download.html

Comment: yeah kinda late. I ditched the whole project eventually because Adobe's API and extendscript is just a horrid undocumented mess that would make VB blush.